# Numpy: An efficient way to merge multiple slices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, merge

I have a numpy array

```
test_array = np.arange(100).reshape((4,25))
```

and I want to merge the following cols to form a new array

```
1:3, 2:4, 3:15, 2:24, 6:8, 12:13
```

I know this code will work

```
np.hstack((test_array[:,1:3],test_array[:,2:4],test_array[:,3:15],test_array[:,2:24],test_array[:,6:8],test_array[:,12:13]))
```

But if there is any better way to avoid copying so many 'test_array', something like:

```
np.hstack((test_array[:,[1:3 2:4 3:15 2:24 6:8 12:13]]))
```

Comment: There are ways to make this operation nicer to read and write, but unfortunately none that avoid copying the data.

Comment: It appears np.r_ is an efficient way to do this, just like in MATLAB

Comment: Yes, it is a nice solution. I just wanted you to be aware that it doesn't avoid copying.

Comment: thanks Nils:) actually in my code, the array name of "test_array" is very long, which made the text flooded everywhere. np.r helps me tidy up a bit:)

Comment: You are concatenating the slices after indexing, `r_` does the concatenation before indexing.  They are roughly equivalent in speed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`np.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) to create the respective range of indices from your slices. It also accepts multiple slice at once.

```
In [25]: test_array[:, np.r_[1:3, 2:4, 3:15, 2:24, 6:8, 12:13]]
Out[25]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  2,  3,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,  2,
         3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23,  6,  7, 12],
       [26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 27,
        28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
        45, 46, 47, 48, 31, 32, 37],
       [51, 52, 52, 53, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 52,
        53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69,
        70, 71, 72, 73, 56, 57, 62],
       [76, 77, 77, 78, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 77,
        78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94,
        95, 96, 97, 98, 81, 82, 87]])
```

Note that as mentioned in comment *using `r_` is nicer to read and write but does't avoid copying data.* And that's because *Advanced Indexing* always returns a copy, unlike the regular indexing that returns views from array.

Comment: It should be noted that using `r_` is nicer to read and write but doesn't avoid copying data.

Comment: @NilsWerner Indeed, thanks for note!

Comment: @NilsWerner np.r_ returns an array so this is just regular slicing. Where does the copying occur?

Comment: @ayhan Copying means that when you select multiple columns from the array it returns copies instead of views (references to the main array).

Comment: @Kasramvd When I tried `test_array[:, np.r_[1:3, 2:4, 3:15, 2:24, 6:8, 12:13]] = 2`  it modified the original array but I think you mean when it is assigned to a variable it creates a copy (which it does). Thank you.

Comment: @ayhan Sorry for the confusion, by copying I mean coping the data not the array itself, necessarily. Read more here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing